# Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: command-line, 20.04

I am new with Ubuntu, so please give detailed answers.

I want to fix this error:

```
Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com
```

Each time I try to update, it shows up.

I have included the following additional packages:

- packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode
- packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams

Screenshot of my terminal:

[image: screenshot of my terminal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I found the solution, thanks for the help though.

There are more answers for this on the original question:
[Connection Refused while apt-get update ubuntu 18.04 over proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045547/connection-refused-while-apt-get-update-ubuntu-18-04-over-proxy)

This solution worked for me,

The issue is that the proxy settings are not being passed to the `sudo` level. You are able to `ping` and `wget` stuff as a normal user since you have the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` settings set for that current user. When you use `sudo`, those environment variables are not passed to the elevated user.

The solution is to use `-E` with `sudo` to pass on those environment variables to the elevated user.

For example, do the following:

```
sudo -E apt-get update
```

It should work.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you've added some "Other Software" to your apt list. A clean one looks like this:

[image]

If you've added more remove them one by one...

If that ppa is not on the list, you might change the server on the "Ubuntu Software" Tab, left of the one on the picture...

**Update**

It looks like that the additional packages are not responsible for the missing server. Select another server as described above..
Since I can connect to `in.ubuntu.archive`your updateserver can't

Comment: I think I have some important files there. Like ms teams and vs code. Will it not affect them ?

Comment: Show me  the list of your repositories

Comment: http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode and https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams

Comment: It would be really great if you could [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1288123/edit) your question and paste your information there - not in a comment. It will help others to understand your problem faster. (I've just done it for you..) **See my revised answer** and change your server

Comment: Since you didn't say that you're using a proxy it was rather difficult to help you...